# How to count number of character Occurrences inside a string and replace selected character with the counts

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to find number of occurrences of a string character and replace the character with the number of occurrence up to that particular index inside the string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] arr = "hello".toCharArray();
    
    arr[2] = '1';
    arr[3] = '2';
    
    System.out.println(arr);
}

Output should be: he12o
```

I know we cant reuse this approach.

Comment: What should be the expected output for input "mathematics"?

Comment: are you looking to count duplicates only, or is there a user input tht provides the character to count?

Comment: what is the output of "helololol"?

Comment: for Mathematics, if we take ch='t'; then the output should be ma1hema2ics

Comment: Shouldn't the expected output be `11121` for `hello`? And what if a char repeat more than 10 times?

Comment: output for helololol, ch='l' , then the output should be he1o2o3o4; if ch='o' then output should be hel1l2l3l

Comment: a simple solution would need a for loop and a counter variable. as you iterate the for loop, if the character matches the given ch, increase the counter and replace the value of array at that index with the char value of the counter, though the cases of counter is larger than single digits needs to be accounted for as mislah mentioned

Comment: Okay okay, you may better mention that the char to be counted is already provided

Comment: @Mislah it shuld be he12o

Comment: @experimentunit1998X can you provide the example solution for that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using primitive methods to manipulate string , we can use the following to have clean code .

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str="helolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololo";
        String checkString="l";
        int count=1;
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        List<String> strLst= new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            strLst.add(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
        }
        
        for(String x : strLst) {
            if(x.equals(checkString)) {
                sb.append(count);
                count++;
            }else {
                sb.append(x);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

The output for the above string will be
`he1o2o3o4o5o6o7o8o9o10o11o12o13o14o15o16o17o18o19o20o21o22o23o24o25o26o27o28o29o30o31o32o33o34o35o36o`

With this implementation , we don't have to worry about splitting the string using substring and checking their index .Will work for 'n' number of repetitive letters.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the output of "helololol"?

> output for helololol, ch='l' , then the output should be he1o2o3o4; if ch='o' then output should be hel1l2l3l

If according to this rule, Can be achieved with a loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char flag = 'l';
    String str = "hellollololollol";
    int num = 1;
    for(int i = 0, len = str.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == flag) {
            str = str.substring(0, i) + num++ + str.substring(i + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Note that if the number of specified characters exceeds 9, it will look weird, If the number of characters exceeds 9, special processing is required：

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char flag = 'l';
    String str = "hellollololollollol";
    int num = 1;
    for(int i = 0, len = str.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == flag) {
            str = str.substring(0, i) + num++ + str.substring(i + 1);
            if (num > 10) {
                len++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

The same problem, if the number of characters exceeds 100, 1000, 10000, special processing is required, because the length of the number added to the string is one bit longer than the original character, how to deal with it flexibly, you need to think about it yourself！